# Expo build Error: Request body larger than maxBodyLength limit

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm attempting to build a signed APK to upload to Google Play.
My app contains some JSON assets, which are 50MB in total.
When I remove them, this error does not occur and my app was built successfully.
So I want to try to increase `maxBodyLength`, but I don't know where it from and how can I change it?

Below are details log from cmd:

```
exp build:android
[exp] Checking if current build exists...
[exp] No currently active or previous builds for this project.
? Would you like to upload a keystore or have us generate one for you?
If you don't know what this means, let us handle it! :)
 false
[exp] Publishing...
[exp] Warning: Not using the Expo fork of react-native. See https://docs.expo.io/.
[exp] Building iOS bundle
[exp] Building Android bundle
[exp] Analyzing assets
[exp] Uploading assets
[exp] No assets changed, skipped.
[exp] Uploading JavaScript bundles
[exp] Request body larger than maxBodyLength limit
[exp] Error: Request body larger than maxBodyLength limit
    at Writable.RedirectableRequest.write (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\exp\node_modules\follow-redirects\index.js:66:24)
at Writable.RedirectableRequest.end (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\exp\node_modules\follow-redirects\index.js:78:10)
at dispatchHttpRequest (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\exp\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\http.js:228:11)
at httpAdapter (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\exp\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\http.js:18:10)
at dispatchRequest (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\exp\node_modules\axios\lib\core\dispatchRequest.js:52:10)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
```

Comment: Make sure your assets are less than 10MB each